# Embedding video into a landing page

Tags: marketing-cloud, landing-page, video

I'm trying to embed a Youtube video into a landing page

```
           <script runat="server"> 
             Platform.Load("core", "1");
          document.write("<iframe title='Video player' type=\"text/html\" width='600' height='300' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/W-Q7RMpINVo'frameborder='0' allowFullScreen></iframe>";
          </script>
```

This is thowing 500 internal error.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: why would you use `runat="server"` on a landing page ?

Comment: Right you don't need it there, still dong it with     <script type="text/javascript">     
doesn't throw an error but it doesn't work either

Comment: you didn't close the () in your document.write() - which is likely what is throwing the error.  But that being said, the accepted answer is a better solution.

Comment: Good point @Gortonington ,  I can avoid the error with that. Still, the only way I can see the video is with Selim code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use HTML for adding video next to SSJS code.

```
<script runat="server"> 
             Platform.Load("core", "1");
          </script>
<html>
  <head>
    <body>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/W-Q7RMpINVo" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>

    </body>
  </head>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Selim, that works. You actually don't need the <script> </script> part, it works fine with the iframe.

Comment: I wrote that part just for showing you can add some SSJS code above HTML part. You are welcome :)